# Generate QR-Code using Blackberry 10 BarcodeGenerator API

Tags: qr-code, blackberry-10

I am looking for code snip to generate QR-Code using Blackberry 10 BarcodeGenerator API.

Code snip is missing in API doc [BarcodeGenerator](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__cascades__multimedia__barcodegenerator.html)

**EDIT**

As I am trying to using the API like below,

```
BarcodeGenerator barcodeGenerator;
bb::ImageData  imageData = barcodeGenerator.generate(BarcodeFormat::QrCode , "Generate QR-code");
imageView->setImage(Image(imageData));
```

it simply saying API is protected. Getting below error message,

> C:/bbndk/target_10_3_1_995/qnx6/usr/include/bb/cascades/multimedia/BarcodeGenerator.hpp:158:31:
>   error: 'bb::ImageData
>   bb::cascades::multimedia::BarcodeGenerator::generate(int, const
>   QString&)' is protected ../src/applicationui.cpp:46:73: error: within
>   this context

**EDIT 2**

I extend the class BarcodeGenerator instead QObject and the QR code generated successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need code snippet, there's only [one method to call](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__cascades__multimedia__barcodegenerator.html#function-generate-filename-format-data) to generate a bar code. As it is a `Q_INVOKABLE` method, it can be called by your QML too.

Just tell us where you're stuck and what you have tried and we'll be able to help.

Comment: .@Roger Leblanc I have used the API as you suggested. Thank you very much for your support :)